# How to generate foreign key constraint in Greenplum (PgadminIII)

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I am trying to generate foreign key constraint in Greenplum (Postgres). Its shows warning as below,

> WARNING:  Referential integrity (FOREIGN KEY) constraints are not supported in Greenplum Database, will not be enforced.

can anyone help me with this and explain how to add a foreign key.

Comment: Does Greenplum support row level triggers? If so, create a trigger that checks the value in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum Doesnt support foriegn key constraint, if you try to create one, it will be created but not enforced

Also triggers are very limited, DML operation cant be performed using triggers

Comment: Yes but pls tell me how to achieve this..?